# retrieving essential data from a webpage using python

Tags: python, get, urllib2, beautifulsoup, urllib

Following is a part of a webpage i downloaded with urlretrieve (urllib). I want to write only this data from the webpage given below in to another text file as:

```
ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS-IV, 4 ,36 ,40 , F
ENVIRONMENTAL STUDIES, 47, 36, 83 , p
...
..
.
```

likeways..
which module should i use?, which all commands??

thanx in advance..:)

### part of the webpage

```
<td>ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS-IV</td>
        <td align=center>4</td>
        <td align=center>36</td>
        <td align=center>40</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>       <td>EIT402    </td>
        <td>ENVIRONMENTAL STUDIES</td>
        <td align=center>47</td>
        <td align=center>36</td>
        <td align=center>83</td>
        <td align=center>P</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#DA9292'>       <td>EIT403    </td>
        <td>SYSTEM PROGRAMMING</td>
        <td align=center>40</td>
        <td align=center>36</td>
        <td align=center>76</td>
        <td align=center>P</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>       <td>EIT404    </td>
        <td>MICROPROCESSOR BASED DESIGN</td>
        <td align=center>3</td>
        <td align=center>35</td>
        <td align=center>38</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#DA9292'>       <td>EIT405    </td>
        <td>PROGRAMMING PARADIGMS</td>
        <td align=center>42</td>
        <td align=center>36</td>
        <td align=center>78</td>
        <td align=center>P</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>       <td>EIT406    </td>
        <td>COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS</td>
        <td align=center>9</td>
        <td align=center>35</td>
        <td align=center>44</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#DA9292'>       <td>EIT407    </td>
        <td>DATA STRUCTURE LAB</td>
        <td align=center>10</td>
        <td align=center>35</td>
        <td align=center>45</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>       <td>EIT408    </td>
        <td>PROGRAMMING  ENVIRONMENTS  LAB</td>
        <td align=center>20</td>
        <td align=center>25</td>
        <td align=center>45</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: "which module should i use?"  You should search.  Right here on Stack Overflow.  If  you search, you find that almost everyone suggests Beautiful Soup.  Everyone else suggests lxml.  Now, please close the question, since it's been asked dozens of times with the same two answers each time.

Comment: use `urllib2` for scraping, `beautifulsoup` for parsing, and ideally the `csv` module for writing out your file. As @S.Lott mentioned, lots of relevant questions on the site. Ask again when you've had a go and encounter a problem or need more insight on something specific. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    infname  = 'htmltable.html'
    outfname = 'courses.txt'

    with open(infname) as inf:
        html = inf.read()

    doc   = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = doc.find('table',{'id':'content'})

    with open(outfname, 'w') as outf:
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            id,name,a,b,c,d = [cell.getText().strip() for cell in row.findAll('td')]
            outf.write("{name}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}\n".format(id=id, name=name, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

works quite nicely if you assume the saved page starts like

```
<html><head><title>Data Table</title></head><body>
<table id='content'>
<tr align=left bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>       <td>EIT402    </td>
    <td>ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS-IV</td>
        <td align=center>4</td>
        <td align=center>36</td>
        <td align=center>40</td>
        <td align=center>F</td>
    </tr>
```

resulting in

```
ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS-IV, 4, 36, 40, F
ENVIRONMENTAL STUDIES, 47, 36, 83, P
SYSTEM PROGRAMMING, 40, 36, 76, P
MICROPROCESSOR BASED DESIGN, 3, 35, 38, F
PROGRAMMING PARADIGMS, 42, 36, 78, P
COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS, 9, 35, 44, F
DATA STRUCTURE LAB, 10, 35, 45, F
PROGRAMMING  ENVIRONMENTS  LAB, 20, 25, 45, F
```