# Python - Error Parsing HTML w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I'm developing an app that inputs data onto a webpage shopping cart and verifies the total. That works fine, however, I am having issue with parsing the HTML output.

A previous discussion; [retrieving essential data from a webpage using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315856/retrieving-essential-data-from-a-webpage-using-python), recommended using BeautifulSoup to make solve said user's problem.

I've borrowed some of the python code, and got it to work on a MacOS system. However when I copied the code over to an ubuntu installation, I'm seeing a strange error.

**The Code (where I'm seeing the issue):

```
response = opener.open(req)
html = response.read()
doc = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)

table = doc.find('tr', {'id':'carttablerow0'})

dump = [cell.getText().strip() for cell in table.findAll('td')]

print "\n Catalog Number: %s \n Description: %s \n Price: %s\n" %(dump[0], dump[1], dump[5])
```

**The Error ( on the ubuntu server)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./shopping_cart_checker.py", line 49, in <module>
        dump = [cell.getText().strip() for cell in table.findAll('td')]
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I think I've narrowed it down to getText() being the culprit. But I'm not certain why this works on MacOS and not ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Hi Guys,

Thank you for the various suggestions. I've attempted most of them, (incorporating the "if cell" statement into the code, however it still isn't working.

@ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams -- Here's a copy of the HTML I'm attempting to strip:

http://pastebin.com/WdaeExnC

Comment: We don't know what your HTML looks like.

Comment: Whatever `td` it's happening on doesn't have any text in it.

Answer (score 0):

As to why it doesn't work on Ubutntu, no idea. However, you can try this:

```
dump = [(cell.getText() if cell.getText() else '').strip() for cell in table.findAll('td')]
```

Comment: Or: `dump = [(cell.getText() or '').strip() for cell in table.findAll('td')]`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the code but with the HTML you are reading, what I would do is changing your code to do this:

```
dump = [cell.getText().strip() for cell in table.findAll('td') if cell]
```

That way if cell is None it will not try to execute getText and just skip that cell. You should debug if you can, i recommend you to use pdb or ipdb (the one i like to use). Here is a [tutorial](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/python-debugger/), with that you can stop just before the line and print values, etc.